# Center a Table inside a TD

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have a very simple problem: I need to center a table inside a TD element. If I were using HTML 4 I'd do it like this:

```
​<table style="border:solid;width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table style="border:solid; width:50%">
                <tr>
                    <td >I must be in the center</td>                    
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>                    
    </tr>
</table>​
```

But I'm trying not to use deprecated attributes and do it the CSS way. I already tried this:

```
<td style="text-align:center">
```

And this:

```
<td style="margin: 0 auto">
```

And the tables keeps in the left-side of the cell. Any suggestions?

Comment: Table based layout, nooooooooo!

Comment: I know, but I have no choice :(

Comment: There's practically always a choice lol

Comment: @ChrisW. not in case of HTML emails :(

Comment: Why are table-based layouts bad? I find them simpler than fudging around with css till kingdom come.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You had the right idea with `margin:auto 0;` just take off the 0.

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cxnR8/**

```
<table style="border:solid;width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="margin:auto;border:solid; width:50%">
                <tr>
                    <td >I must be in the center</td>                    
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>                    
    </tr>
</table>​
```

But, more importantly, do you really need to use tables and in-line styling?

Comment: That's it, but the align attribute of the TD is not necessary at all, right?

Comment: Yep, you're correct. Even though browsers may choose to support it through legacy/quirks mode, the `align` attribute is not part of the HTML5 spec and you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 4):

Center the table using the deprecated `align=""` attribute.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>in the middle</td>                    
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>                    
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Comment: this work in obsolete css version :D . thank man, I dont want to use margin

Answer (score 1):

Your seccond suggestion is correct. [See this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/V5rRC/).

HTML:

```
<table class="outer">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="inner">
                <tr>
                    <td>in the middle</td>                    
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>                    
    </tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
.outer
{
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.inner
{
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
​
```